# Unable to move element to right

Tags: spacing, templates, cv, resume

I have the following file `testCV.tex`:

```
%testCV.tex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Medium Length Professional CV - RESUME CLASS FILE
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% This class file defines the structure and design of the template. 
%
% Original header:
% Copyright (C) 2010 by Trey Hunner
%
% Copying and distribution of this file, with or without modification,
% are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
% notice and this notice are preserved. This file is offered as-is,
% without any warranty.
%
% Created by Trey Hunner and modified by www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass{testcls} % Use the custom testcls.cls style
\usepackage[left=0.5in,top=0.5in,right=0.5in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry} % Document margins
\begin{document}
    \begin{rSection}{Projects}{LinkToGitHub}
    \end{rSection}
\end{document}
```

It's associated `testcls.cls` file contains:

```
\ProvidesClass{testcls}
\LoadClass[11pt,letterpaper]{article} % Font size and paper type
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
\usepackage{array} % Required for boldface (\bf and \bfseries) tabular columns
\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers

% Defines the rSection environment for the large sections within the CV
\newenvironment{rSection}[2]{ % 1st input argument - section name, 2nd input argument - relevant links.
  \sectionskip
  \MakeUppercase{{\bf #1}} \hfill {#2} % Section title and relevant links
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
}

\def\sectionlineskip{\medskip} % The space above the horizontal line for each section 
\def\sectionskip{\medskip} % The space after the heading section
```

The issue is that `LinkToGitHub` has a weird indent on it's right that I just can't remove.

[image]

I'm a beginner at LaTeX, so I got a template for my CV and started fiddling with it. It's been fine so far until this.

Comment: That is not your code, right?

Comment: @Johannes_B It is not my code. Today's my first day with LaTeX (but not programming in general).

Comment: Ok, word of advice: Read an introduction like [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html). It will take about two afternoons. Though i agree, that learning from existing code is good, i also have to say that learning from bad code is a bad idea. Unfortunately, Trey's code is an example of that.

Comment: Try putting `\\ ` after `\MakeUppercase{{\bf #1}} \hfill {#2}`. Also give `%` at end of each lines in `rSection` environment.

Comment: Please also have a look at the copyright and licensing stuff.

Comment: @Johannes_B adding the copyright to the file. It is indeed by Trey Hunner

Comment: @Jagath Ah, putting \ \ did it! Could you please explain what's happening?

Comment: @Jagath okay I take it back. Now there's a lot of space between the \hrule and the text.

Comment: You can change it to `\hbox to \textwidth{\MakeUppercase{\bf #1}\hfill #2}`. There should be a line break between first line and the rule.

Comment: The template is doing this on purpose. No, not really ;-) Probably nobody knows what the  `parfill` option does. Replace the whole line loading `parskip` with `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`.

Comment: @Johannes_B Can you post these responses as answers? Then I can get the flow of it better.

Comment: @Jagath could you post an answer as well?

Comment: This class `testcls.cls` is based on `resume.cls` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current MWE, you could change the following macro in the class file:

```
\newenvironment{rSection}[2]{ % 1st input argument - section name, 2nd input argument - relevant links.
  \sectionskip
  \MakeUppercase{{\bf #1}} \hfill {#2} % Section title and relevant links
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
}
```

to:

```
\newenvironment{rSection}[2]{% 1st input argument - section name, 2nd input argument - relevant links.
  \sectionskip%
  \hbox to \textwidth{\MakeUppercase{\bf #1}\hfill #2}% Section title and relevant links
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
}{}
```

Comment: You forgot to define the end-part of the newenvironment definition.

Comment: I finally used this solution as it was the easiest fix. @Johannes_B your solution worked too.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Sorry. Now I have added it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why somebody would use a  template for a cv, since you want changes anyway. [I am really confused](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/)

The following should do, what you want. I removed `\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}` from the class file, since it causes the behaviour. Instead, i simply changed the `parindent` to zero. That is ok for a CV document.

I also changed the environment in question a bit, for example the `end` part was missing.

[image: abhidivekar]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Medium Length Professional CV
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.0 (8/5/13)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Trey Hunner (http://www.treyhunner.com/)
%
% Important note:
% This template requires the resume.cls file to be in the same directory as the
% .tex file. The resume.cls file provides the resume style used for structuring the
% document.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % Document margins

\name{John Smith} % Your name
\address{123 Broadway \\ City, State 12345} % Your address
\address{123 Pleasant Lane \\ City, State 12345} % Your secondary addess (optional)
\address{(000)~$\cdot$~111~$\cdot$~1111 \\ john@smith.com} % Your phone number and email

\usepackage{showframe}% visual aid
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\renewenvironment{rSection}[2]{% 1st input argument - section name, 2nd input argument - relevant links.
    \sectionskip%
    \MakeUppercase{{\bfseries#1}}\hfill #2 \par% Section title and relevant links
    \vspace{-.5\baselineskip}
    \rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}% Horizontal line
    \sectionlineskip%
}{}

\begin{rSection}{Projects}{LinkToGitHub}
    wombat
\end{rSection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do I get rid of the borders surrounding the document?

Comment: @abhidivekar `\usepackage{showframe}% visual aid` ... delete it.